# When adding new product Category Search box Not displaying results

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog, catalogsearch

When I add a new product and then want to add the product categories I am unable to type then in to the search box and get any results. Is there something I need to change? See attached image.
[image]

Comment: Check your browser console while searching. it might be a javascript error blocking the script to run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1, **after every product uploaded, you need a re-index required.**

In Magento 2 to run the Reindex, you should setup the cron job.

If you want **reindex immediate** then you should run  `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` command from Terminal

**How to Setup Cron in Magento 2?**

You have to have SSH access to your Magento 2 installation in order to run it as smooth as it should. Make sure, you get the access.

As soon as you have access to your instance, go to the Magento 2 root directory and run `php bin/magento cron:install`. That should be enough.

In case the only way for you is to add the cron through an admin interface like cpanel; try to add the cron jobs line by line.

```
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Depending in the admin panel, you might have to enter the path to the PHP binary. If you are not sure which path it is, just try php.